# display error if $_GET['something'] no result

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

so im messing around abit with query strings etc, however i want to display an error if there is no result from this code:

```
else {
          if (isset($_GET['Category'])) {
            $category = $_GET['Category'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Category='$category'";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(':category'=>$category));
            while($cat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {  
              ?>

              <div class="post_body">
                <div class="post_header">
                  <h2><?php echo "$cat[Title]";?></h2>
                </div>
                <?php echo "$cat[Post]";?>
                <a class="read-more" href="?ID=<?php echo "$cat[ID]";?>#lamna_kommentar">Lämna en kommentar</a>
                <hr>
                <div class="post_footer">
                  <span class="left_span">
                    <strong>Av: </strong><?php echo "$cat[Author]";?>
                    <strong>Kategori: </strong><?php echo "$cat[Category]";?>
                  </span>
                  <span class="right_span">
                    <strong>Datum: </strong><?php echo date_format( new DateTime($cat['Date']), 'd M Y, H:i' );?>
                    <strong>Inlägg: #</strong><?php echo "$cat[ID]";?>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>  
              <?php 
            }
          }
```

as it works now this link shows  `a class="read-more" href="?ID=<?php echo "$cat[ID]";?>#lamna_kommentar">Lämna en kommentar</a>` but nothing else when there is no result.

i really cant figure this out, probably something easy, any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have anything in your querystring named "Category"

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Comment: @tadman yea thanks, not a production site or so atm so i havent really bothered

Comment: @perkällström That's the oldest excuse in the books. Learn to do it right and do it that way all the time.

Comment: It's a perfect time to fix it then. This is something way too dangerous to forget about.

Comment: @Barmar yea it might be an excuse, but in this case its true :) but yea i should make a habit on doing it correct in the first place :)

Comment: You're only displaying one post in the category, is that really what you want? You should add `LIMIT 1` to the query so the database doesn't bother returning all the other posts that you're ignoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the number of rows that were returned:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    // display error
} else {
    while ($cat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: if u use rowCount instead it works, thanks! :)

Comment: Oops, mixing up PDO and mysqli, sorry about that

Comment: No worries, thanks again :)